# Customizing OneSignal launch buttons for iOS notification

Tags: ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

So I'm having an issue:
I'm creatin this request to send push notification and specifying only one additional button:

```
{
...
"buttons":[{"id": "view", "text": "View"}]
}
```

I also have my setting

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true);
```

set to true.
When application gets notification I'm checking if "view" button was pressed (because by default another option 'Close' is always shown) - then I'm routing user to custom action:

```
var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
  if (jsonData.additionalData) {
    if (jsonData.additionalData.actionSelected == "view")
      //custom code executes
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I'm clicking "Close" or tapping on notification in notification bar both actions have name "__DEFAULT__".

Is there is the way to determine whether user clicked 'Close' on notification inside an application or he clicked notification in iOS notification center? Because theese are 2 completely different behavior types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to tell the different between an alert click and from the notification center you will need to disable `enableInAppAlertNotification` and display your own alert based off if `jsonData.isActive` is to `true`.